# Nested Navigators React Native

Tags: android, react-native, tabnavigator

I am using TabNavigator as per this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab. 
The app already has Navigator from react-native to handle Navigation between different Screens. The Navigator is connected to the redux store. My problem is when I go to any screen after clicking on the button on Tab Screen it goes to the particular screen (Which is handled by Navigator) but while coming back it doesn't come back to the Tab Screen.

I also looked into https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting but I want to do it with react Navigator.

Any suggestion/guide to this will be really helpful.

Comment: Please check these two articles, nesting drawer navigation has been explained elegantly. This will resolve your problem:

https://medium.com/@gsveitch/nested-navigators-need-new-i-ndices-f63eeb69c712

https://medium.com/@ivanzotov/react-native-deep-linking-with-authorization-screen-drawer-and-nested-navigators-in-react-4f702b1520a0